# How to exclude folders from HTTPS redirects with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect, https

I am trying to redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS, but I don't need to redirect all content, I would like to exclude some folders (like the `bower_components folder`) to avoid loading twice the javascript and css content.

The code that I am using on the .htaccess is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

How can I update the `.htaccess` to exclude folders on the redirect?

Comment: Beware: mixed content may be unsafe (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content) and 301 permanent redirects are a dangerous one-way street (see http://getluky.net/2010/12/14/301-redirects-cannot-be-undon/).

Answer (score 6):

Add more RewriteCond directives to filter the paths that you do not want to redirect. For example

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*/bower_components/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```